# Is there a dwarf nectarine tree that would be suitable for indoor/outdoor life?

Tags: fruit-trees, indoors, variety-selection, nectarines

I have an apartment in Brooklyn with a south-east facing deck.  In the summer it gets a lot of light.   Indoors, I also have lots of windows facing that direction.  I'd like to get a nectarine tree and have it indoors in the winter, and outdoors in the summer (I can use a dolly to move the pot).  Are there dwarf varieties of this type that would do well in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have first hand experience, but I do know with appropriate tree stock selection, the right conditions, care, you can most definitely make it work.

- [Dwarfing Plants:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarfing#Plants)

> As with animals, plants can be dwarfed through **[genetic engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_engineering#Agriculture) and selective breeding**, but can also undergo natural, morphological changes to acclimatize to environmental stresses such as soil quality, light, drought, flood, cold, infection, and herbivory resulting in a dwarfed stature.

This, [Growing Dwarf Fruit Trees and Nut Trees](http://www.motherearthnews.com/Organic-Gardening/1986-03-01/Dwarf-Trees-Fruit-Nuts.aspx), appears to be a pretty good, useful article on the subject of "Dwarf Fruiting Trees". Below are a few bullet points I've picked out of that article & stuff I've picked up over the years:

- For your situation, I believe you will be best served with a [genetic dwarf nectarine tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_engineering#Agriculture). These trees have been available to home gardeners since the mid to late 1960's.
- Dwarf peach and nectarine trees should be readily available in a large selection of cultivars. Look for ones that claim to be "disease resistant", this "should" make maintenance that bit easier.
- Dwarf peach and nectarine trees are short, shrubby trees, grow to about 6 to 10ft (1800 to 3000mm) tall and wide.
- Dwarf fruit trees fruit earlier than their "standard" family members.
- Dwarf fruit trees have a high density of bloom, which results in a large fruit crop (for the size of the tree).
- Due to the high density of bloom, pruning is **not as** important to stimulate flower and fruit production. Note, appropriate pruning should still be undertaken for the overall health of the fruit tree.
- Easy maintenance due to their small size eg No need for ladders.
- Peach and nectarine trees need plenty of sunshine and warmth.
- Plant the dwarf fruit tree in a "suitably" sized container (with good drainage), basically the bigger the better.
- Plant the dwarf fruit tree in "good quality" growing medium, either purchase a "high quality" container (soil) mix or mix your own.
- Mulch with compost, this will help feed the "container" (bound) tree slowly.
- In the first year, remove **all** fruits, this will allow the roots and the tree itself to get better established.
- In the second year, remove ¾ of the fruits.
- The first year or two is all about building strong foundations.
- From the third year onward, you will want to remove (thin) 50% of the fruit, doing so will greatly help your tree remain healthy, prolong its life and result in much better quality fruit (the ones that remain on the tree to ripen).
- As is the case with "most" plants, the more (appropriate) care you give, the more years of enjoyment you can expect back from your dwarf fruit tree.